# How can I get the GUID of my disc partitions?

Tags: delphi, wmi, guid, disk

I'm using WMI to get all disk information, like drives, drive letters, etc. but I have not found out how I could get the UUID/GUID of each partition.

Comment: If you can live without WMI you could use the WinAPI: it's basically [`DeviceIoControl( ... IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX ... )`](https://www.delphipraxis.net/186877-p.html). Works for me almost instantly with D7 on Win7.

Comment: Do you mean UUID of the partition, or of the volume?https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e7b2ddd6-f245-49ed-8fec-3b6e08e75369/how-do-i-find-the-partition-guid?forum=winservergen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several **WMI** classes to access **Disks** and **Partitions** information:

- Win32_Volume
- Win32_DiskDrive
- Win32_DiskPartition

And these two, which relate the previous ones to each other:

- Win32_DiskDrivePhysicalMedia
- Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition

Specifically using `Win32_Volume` you can access the GUID of the existing partitions.
You can test it from shell:

```
> wmic volume get Driveletter, DeviceID
```

You get data like this:

[image]

Using delphi, you can use some components, or one code like this (by Code Creator -Rodrigo Ruz-):

```
program GetWMI_Info;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}   
uses
  SysUtils, ActiveX, ComObj, Variants;
   
procedure  GetWin32_VolumeInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('Description     %s',[String(VarToStrDef(FWbemObject.Description, ''))]));// String
    Writeln(Format('DeviceID        %s',[String(VarToStrDef(FWbemObject.DeviceID, ''))]));// String
    Writeln(Format('DriveLetter     %s',[String(VarToStrDef(FWbemObject.DriveLetter, ''))]));// String
    Writeln(Format('DriveType       %d',[Integer(VarToStrDef(FWbemObject.DriveType, ''))]));// Uint32
    Writeln(Format('Label           %s',[String(VarToStrDef(FWbemObject.Label, ''))]));// String
    Writeln(Format('Name            %s',[String(VarToStrDef(FWbemObject.Name, ''))]));// String
    Writeln(Format('SerialNumber    %d',[Integer(VarToStrDef(FWbemObject.SerialNumber, ''))]));// Uint32
    Writeln('');
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetWin32_VolumeInfo;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I used "Win32_DiskDrive" instead of your " Win32_Volume" and that caused DeviceID to have another meaning. Therefore I couldn't find the GUID. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell. First, get a list of partitions:

*Get-Partition*

Then from the list, find the partition number of the one that interests you. Next run the following command (substituting the appropriate partition number):

*Get-Partition | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.PartitionNumber -eq 3} | Select-Object -Property*

From the list of properties you will see the *Guid* property with your partition's GUID.